# XM Cloud Starter kit - Unhandled Runtime Error - Error: Could not resolve site for name abc

Tags: xm-cloud

In **XM Cloud** I created a project and environment cloning the foundation head repo as a starter kit.

I ran the `init.ps1`, ran `npm install` and exchanged the package references in `.env` as I'm running **Windows 10**.

I connect my local running code with XM Cloud Preview Endpoint running

```
npm run start:connected
```

When calling the site on `localhost:3000` I get the following Error:

[image: XM Cloud runtime error]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error while doing my initial setup with `XMCloud`.
Please note, the name of the site is case-sensitive, so set the proper value in `JSS_APP_NAME`.

If it is still not fixed, please try the site name without any space.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states the site is not correctly resolved in CdpPageView.tsx. It seems that the value set in .env file is not correctly picked up and the default value is taken from config.js[image]

Just name this value to your app_name or sitename.

This has been addressed with the Product Team and is currently being fixed.